# How can I purge unused translatable strings from the translation interface?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

During the development, the wording changed quite a lot. When I generate translation jobs with tmgmt module (or by any other means), all the old wordings are listed as well.

Is it possible to have a fresh start? Per hand removal would also be ok.